# HTML5 Local Storage stringify's and stores EACH object reference

Tags: javascript, json, html, local-storage

With the following JSON:

```
var myObj = {name: 'my obj', does: 'nothing'};
var myObjArr = [myObj, myObj, myObj];
```

When storing myObjArr to local storage, the myObj JSON is wrtten 3 times, taking up 3 times as much storage space, i.e:

```
"[{"name":"my obj","does":"nothing"},{"name":"my obj","does":"nothing"},{"name":"my obj","does":"nothing"}]"
```

Obviously this is going to present scalability issues. Can anyone recommend an optimal solution? So far I've had to resort to using ID's, a la relational databases.

```
var objects = {0: {name: 'my obj', does: 'nothing'}};
var myObjArr = [{obj: 0}, {obj: 0}, {obj: 0}];
```

Update - the question is how to represent this hierarchy in local storage when all data is ultimately stored as key/value strings. Resorting to relational database concepts seems old-school.

Comment: I guess your example object will sometimes change? Because it looks like you just have one identical object three times - will it always be a quantity of identical elements or will they change?

Comment: @Henry this is just an example to show if an object contains more than one reference to another object, it will be stringified for each and every reference which wastes space, plus you lose the many to one connection when you parse the JSON back from local storage... surely there must be a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more appropriate technology would be [IndexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/) used as an object store, however it isn't [supported](http://caniuse.com/indexeddb) by many browsers yet.

EDIT: You'll want to browse through the documentation of the [structured clone algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-dom-interfaces.html#internal-structured-cloning-algorithm) that is used when copying an object into IndexedDB - it looks like references are maintained per record, but [adding](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#widl-IDBObjectStore-add) multiple records will not result in each record referencing objects that were shared in the JavaScript memory space.